# Forcefully Install windows 10 drivers on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, intel-graphics, display-driver

I would like to install windows 10 graphics drivers on my windows 7. Since the manufacturers does not provide drivers for my 8th gen intel processeur. Is there a way I can get windows 10 drivers installed on windows 7 anyway.

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank @DavidPostill for the information It wont happen again. I have create a new question here https://superuser.com/questions/1394240/where-to-find-intel-8th-gen-graphics-drivers-for-windows-7

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to install windows 10 graphics drivers on my windows 7. Since the manufacturers does not provide drivers for my 8th gen intel processor.

The drivers are not compatible with Windows 7.  The Windows Driver Model version is different between Windows 7 and Windows 10.

The Intel drivers you speak of will not function on Windows 7.  For the same reason, Windows 7 display drivers cannot be used on Windows 10 the opposite is true.

Simply stated, what you want, is not possible

Comment: What are my options then to get the drivers to work on my windows 7?

Comment: There are no options, as stated it is not possible.

Comment: Will I understand that the graphics card would be close to impossible. But let's say for my touchpad if the touchpad existed in a similar computer that supported windows 7 would it be possible to install it?

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach - Device driver compatibility depends on the `.INF` file.  However, your question as it's currently written isn't about any device driver, it is specifically about device drivers.

Comment: You are correct I should have giving more information. My end goal is to get windows 7 working on a intel 8th gen processor how exactly i get donne doesn't matter to me I try to tackle it one probleme at the time. Right now I am I trying to get the touchpad working for my .ASUS VivoBook S510UAR I want to know if there is a possibility. For example finding a older version of the laptop that supported windows 7 and has the same touchpad.

Comment: If the only GPU you have, is the Intel iGPU, then what you want isn't possible.  Intel does not provide Windows 7 compatible display drivers for your iGPU.

Comment: UPDATE I have talked with a Intel agent and he has told me that their exits a unofficial link for the graphics driver.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach - I am not going to modify my answer.  I stand by the accuracy of it, given the Intel agent was unable to provide an actual link the driver, I cannot do anything with the new information.  Even if they did, I have reason to believe, it wouldn't actually work.